# How to apply function to matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to apply a function to each elements of matrix. I do it with for loops. But since the speed is critical for me, I was wondering whether can someone help me to make it more faster by removing for loops ?

Here is my code :

```
Nrow=size(W,1);
Ncol=size(W,2);

for R=1:Nrow
    for C=1:Ncol
        W(R,C)=(sign(W(R,C))) * (max((abs(W(R,C))- lambda),0));
    end
end
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read the [Vectorization](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/750/vectorization#t=201702101445209097363) topic that we have in Stackoverflow Documentation.

Answer (score 5):

All of the operations that you've shown actually will *already* operate (element-wise) on matrices with the exception that `*` is matrix multiplication where you'll want `.*` instead to perform [element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

```
W = sign(W) .* max(abs(W) - lambda, 0);
```

Comment: @Brick No, it's an element-wise maximum between each value in `W` and `0`. To get maximum of a row or column would requite `max(data, [], dim)`